# How to timeout idle user sessions in Redshift?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-redshift

I am looking for a way to terminate user sessions that have been inactive or open for an arbitrary amount of time in Redshift. I noticed that in **STV_SESSIONS** I have a large number of sessions open, often for the same user, sometimes having been initialized days earlier. While I understand that this might be a symptom of a larger issue with the way some things close out of Redshift, I was hoping for a configurable timeout solution.

In the AWS documentation I found **PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND** (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND.html), but I was hoping for a more automatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Workload Management Configuration in AWS redshift. Where you can set the user group, query group, and timeout sessions. You can group all the same users together and assign a group name to them and set the timeout session for them. 
 This is how I do it. Set the Query queue, based on your priority and then set concurrency level for the user group and the timeout in ms.

[image]

For more information, you can refer to AWS documentation.

 Source - [Workload Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/workload-mgmt-config.html)

 - [Configuring Workload Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/workload-mgmt-config.html)

 Its pretty easy and straight forward. 
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Ooo just saw this, will try when I have a moment and report back. Thanks!

Comment: This timeout setting is for the duration of a running query, not the duration of a session. I don't believe there's a session timeout parameter. If there was, you would expect it to be documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-parameter-groups.html

Answer (score 4):

the timeout is only for timing out queries and not for a session.

**Timeout (ms)**

```
The maximum time, in milliseconds, queries can run before being canceled. If a read-only query, such as a SELECT statement, is canceled due to a WLM timeout, WLM attempts to route the query to the next matching queue based on the WLM Queue Assignment Rules. If the query doesn't match any other queue definition, the query is canceled; it is not assigned to the default queue. For more information, see WLM Query Queue Hopping. WLM timeout doesn’t apply to a query that has reached the returning state. To view the state of a query, see the STV_WLM_QUERY_STATE system table.

JSON property: max_execution_time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the newly introduced `idle session timeout` feature in Redshift. It is available both when [creating a user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html) and post creation ([using Alter statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_USER.html)). Lookup the `SESSION TIMEOUT` parameter.